# Delete document from document library on basis of "Document ID" - CSOM or REST

Tags: rest, csom, delete, document-id

We are developing an API to be called by external application.

To have unqiue document ID across Site Collection we have enabled "Document ID service"

Using CSOM we have been able to implement

1. Upload File
2. Download file by passing 'Document ID'

However struggling to file a way to delete document using 'Document ID'. That is the caller will only be passing the unique Document ID and we have to delete it.
Googling around getting **SOM** code
[Delete document from document Library Using Document ID](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a659b698-fe6b-4b54-b488-7a6c4a711bfa/delete-document-from-document-library-using-document-id?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

As we are implementing it for SharePoint 2016 and donot want to use anything  which will run only the Server, we are looking for **CSOM / REST** implementation.

Kindly let know if any further details required.

Answer (score 1):

Document ID value is present in a document library column whose internal name is `_dlc_DocId`.

So, you can use CAML query to find out which document has a particular document ID and based on that you can delete that document.

Here, I am assuming a document library named `Documents` and document ID something like `SOMEUNIQUEID-11-11`

The JSOM implementation would be as below:

```
function deleteFileByDocumentId(documentID){

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq>' + 
        '<FieldRef Name=\'_dlc_DocId\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>UNIQUEID-11-11</Value>' + 
        '</Eq></Where></Query></View>');

    var items = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents').getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        var itemCount = items.get_count();
        for (var i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var oListItem = items.itemAt(i);
            oListItem.deleteObject();
        };

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            console.log("success deleting document");
        }, function(){
            console.log("something went wrong");
        });

    },function(){
        console.log("something went wrong");
    });
}
```

RESTful implementation would be as below (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452356/sharepoint-2013-clientcontext-how-to-delete-specific-list-items-by-multiple-co)):

```
function getItemsToDelete() {

    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$filter=OData__dlc_DocId eq 'SOMEUNIQUEID-11-11'&$select=Title,FileRef";

    return $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $.each(result.d.results, function(index, item){                
                itemsToDelete.push(deleteItem(item));
            });            
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });    
}

function deleteItem(item) {

    var requestUrl = item.__metadata.uri;

    return $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("File with ID " + item.__metadata.id + " successfully deleted!");
        },
        error: function(error) {
             console.log(error);
        }
    });    
}

var itemsToDelete = [];


$.when(getItemsToDelete()).then(function () {
    $.when.apply($, itemsToDelete).then(function(){
        console.log("All docs with unique document ID are deleted!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Gautam, Thank you for the response. However, we will be getting the Document ID. We won't be getting the Library in which the document is. Thus wont be able to use GetbyTitle() 
Kindly advise

Comment: does this mean you won't know where the document is and will only have the ID?

Comment: Hi Lem, yes i know only the "Document Id" (unique Document ID accross entire site-collection). Configured Document ID service

Comment: Then use search to retrieve the item, that will return you the full URL to the item. From there you can grab the web and the DocLib and the nuke it. Edit: There can be more than 1 result! Make sure you cover that ;)